# Minor Update Warnings

Tags: updates

[Screenshot from 2018-10-12 19-32-18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is0kd.png)

[Screenshot from 2018-10-12 19-33-33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnmFF.png)

These are some Warning messages that I usually get whenever I'm trying to update my Applications and Packages from Software Updater,

This problem has been there ever since I updated to last major Update for Ubuntu 18.04 "Bionic Beaver".

What are the Possible reasons for this? And is there any Solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Are you connecting via `ssh` to the server?

Comment: No, I have no idea about what Type of server I'm connecting with! But the problem got solved after when i Completely installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS once again.